# Is there AppWidget callback for when an AppWidget is no longer visible?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I am updating my AppWidgets using a Service which listens to a pub/sub channel and essentially runs in the background forever, updating the AppWidgets whenever an update is received.

I am not concerned about battery life because the device is always plugged in, but I am concerned about CPU and memory usage by these background processes.

Is there a way I can get a notification that the AppWidget is no longer visible (e.g. when the home screen goes away or is swiped to another page)?  I want to be able to toggle listening to the pub/sub channel if the AppWidget is not visible.

[Added]
Or, is there even a synchronous method I can call to check whether an AppWidget is currently visible?

Answer (score 1):

There are [ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED) and [ACTION_APPWIDGET_DISABLED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#ACTION_APPWIDGET_DISABLED) broadcasts that tell when widget is deleted.

Alternatively you can also use [AppWidgetProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html) wrapper and implement `onDelete()` and `onDisable()` methods.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a event that is triggered when the AppWidget is no longer visible but still attached to the AppWidgetHost.